# Задача по поиску кратчайшего пути

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Есть поле <30x30. Мы можем по этому полю проводить линии по вертикали и горизонтали, которые могут пересекаться.

*Пример возможного расположения линий*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правила следующие:

1. Каждая клетка имеет тип 0, 1 или 2. Каждая линия тоже имеет тип 0, 1 или 2.
2. Если линия проходит через свой тип, то штраф равен 0. Если через соседний (0 через 1, 1 через 2 или наоборот), то штраф равен 1. Если через дальний (0 через 2 или наоборот), то штраф равен 5.
3. Начисляется дополнительный штраф за пересечение линий равный количеству линий умноженому на константу N, при этом одним пересечением считается одна общая клетка.

На вход дается: константа N, поле с указанием типов клеток, параметры каждой линий с указанием начала, конца и типа.

Нужно провести заданые линии так, чтобы штраф был минимальным.

Время работы: вообще меня устроит и 5 минут, но лучше было бы уложиться в несколько секунд (хотя бы для полей 10x10).

*Задача вроде простая (на графы), если бы не условие о штрафе за пересечения. Не знаю что делать именно с ним, так что прошу подсказать по поводу него. Может быть есть какие-то готовые алгоритмы для подобных вещей, о которых я не знаю.*

Comment: Интересная задачка. Я бы ее решал итеративно. Провели 1 линию, потом вторую, пересчитали 1, пересчитали 2, и так пока штраф не устаканится.

Comment: Если несколько линий пересекаются в одной точке, то какой штраф?

Comment: За что конкретно штраф N? Если две динии имеют 3 общие клетки, то шртаф 3*N или 1*N? Какое ограничение на число линий?

Comment: @Qwertiy 1) (количество линий в точке-1)*n 2) N задаётся на входе 3) 3n

Comment: Какое ограничение на число линий?

Comment: Было бы круто, если бы вы расписали в посте пример расчёта штрафа для какого-нибудь случая линии

Comment: N может быть любым – и нулевым и отрицательным? Т.е. нельзя предполагать, что пересечение точно увеличит штраф?

Comment: Я так понял, что на вход дается несколько наборов линий. Нужно сделать так, чтобы суммарный штраф был минимальным?

Comment: @Vlad да, именно так

Comment: @Qwertiy штук 30

Comment: Чем-то напоминает задачу трассировки.

Comment: Уточните. Вы пишете -- "Начисляется дополнительный штраф за пересечение линий равный количеству линий умноженому на константу N ...". Может имеется в виду не количество линий, а количество пересечений? И еще -- именно штраф надо минимизировать или все же общую стоимость с учетом штрафа?

Comment: И еще один момент. Допустимы ли  пересечения одной и той же пары линий в смежных клетках? (просто если ответ -- Да, то вроде бы формально получается, что две (или более) линии могут вообще идти по одним и тем же клеткам).

Comment: Чем-то напомнило задачу о двух коммивояжерах многокритериальной оптимизации http://www.itlab.unn.ru/uploads/opt_3_part/03_DD/book_din.pdf
Хотя тут оптимизация вроде по одному критерию

Answer (score 6):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужно оптимизировать путь для каждой из линий. Учтем что вариантов проведения каждой линии будет (для n>2, где n это ребро поля) 4^((n-2)^2) + 4*3^(n-2) + 8. Таким образом, я бы лично искал не "лучший путь" - выдаюший кратчайшее из возможных "растояний", так как поиск такого пути может потребовать ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО времени ,а "хороший путь" - такой, какой мы можем найти за ограниченное наперед время, но который не является обязательно "лучшим из возможных".

Пожалуй тут я вижу два подхода, что то вроде шахматной [алфа-беты](http://%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), правда тут прийдется поломать голову над функцией оценки. Либо, что нибудь типа [муравьиного алгоритма](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/hh781027.aspx).

Comment: Это явно задача с точным решением. Причём какая-то олимпиадная, вероятно. Так что ответ не в тему.

Comment: @Qwertiy Олимпиадные задачи, формулируются, обычно, так что бы программу можно было написать довольно быстро, а тут в любом случае будет довольно много работы "ручками", так что это явно не "олимпиадная задача". Что касается "точного решения", то мне на него будет очень интересно посмотреть, например от вас, так как задачка интересна, в том числе и практически.

Comment: Нет. По формулировке она олимпиадная. На какую-то технику с графами. Я предполагаю, что на потоки. Но решение полное я не придумал. См. мой ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Олимпиадная задача предполагает быстрое написание кода, олимпиады всегда ограничены во времени, поэтому ИМХО нет. Скорее задача напоминает что то из области логистики. Хотя если считать Нобелевскую премию (за транспортную задачу) олимпиадой... :)

Comment: Быстрое - да, но ещё и знание алгоритмов и умение придумать решение. Бинпоиск и потоки на графе пишутся достаточно быстро, чтобы она была олимпиалной. А вот придумать, как конкретно их совместить - это надо понять.

Answer (score 3):

1. Используем бинпоиск по ответу.
   Т. е. ограничиваем максимальный штраф и запускаем решение задачи с таким ограничением. Если решение найдено, то за стоимость не большую данной построить можно. При этом решение не обязано гарантировать минимальность - оно лишь гарантирует существование или несуществование.
   Минимальное значение будет обеспечено бинпоиском.
2. Алгоритм Дейкстры скорее всего к данной задаче неприменим.
   Там есть условие, что если два пути суммарно короче, то лучше пройти по ним, а тут есть штраф за пересечение, который влияет на стоимость.
3. Возникает мысль свести эту задачу к потокам на графе 
   Добавляем общий исток и общий сток, пытаемся прогнать поток с величиной, равной лимиту, перебираемому в бинпоиске.
   Допускаю, что эта идея может быть неверна.
   Допускаю, что от бинпоиска можно отказаться (хотя сомнительно).

На этом пока всё.

Answer (score 3):

А почему бы не воспользоваться [волновым алгоритмом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B8)? Только в классической виде необходимо найти расстояние, Вам же надо минимизировать штраф. Например, представим поле 5х5 с начальными данными для линии `(2,3), (4,1), 1`. Получится следующая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком месте пересечение линий должно учитываться? Жадный алгоритм, скорее всего, неверный.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно дополнительно ввести проверку на наличие в квадрате линии. Можете объяснить, почему он неверен?

Comment: Потому что получится нечто типа жадного алгоритма - некоторые линии приоритетнее других.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, не учел, что линии строятся не по очереди, а одновременно.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача состоит из двух:

1. Аккуратно по заданному полю построить взвешенный граф. Это банальная вычислительная комбинаторика.
2. Примененить алгоритм Дейкстры.

Comment: Как с помощью Дейкстры учитывать штраф за пересечения?

Comment: Все штрафы нужно сосчитать при построении графа на первом этапе. Алгоритм Дейкстры просто найдет вам нужные пути.

Comment: Как штраф за пересечение учесть на первом этапе? Я не знаю кто где пересечётся.

Comment: @danpetruk Ну будет у вас несколько графов на выходе из первого алгоритма. А потом вы найдете оценки для всех них и выберете лучшую

Comment: @gbg если я правильно понял вашу мысль, то асимптотика выходит аж O(n^4)?

Comment: @danpetruk задача классно параллелится. Кроме того, реализовав ее, можно начать думать над эвристиками, хотя бы позволяющими без Дейкстры откинуть часть графов с первого этапа.

Comment: @danpetruk Штрафы начисляются не за пересечения между линиями, а за проход линии по чужому полю. А разметка полей дана изначально и не меняется. По сути линии никак вообще не влияют друг на друга.

Comment: @Cerbo, невнимательно читаешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy это потому что уже иммунитет против жирного текста :)

Answer (score 1):

Искать пути можно алгоритмом Дейкстры, но сначала для каждой линии нужно построить граф особого вида, назовем его граф Д. В узлах графа Д будут либо отдельные клетки со штрафами больше 0, либо множества сопряженных "своих" клеток со штрафами 0. Множества "своих" клеток должны включать клетки в каждую из которох можно попасть не проходя через "чужие", тут надо следить чтобы в эти области не попадали диагональные клетки. Путь в штрафной узел будет равен штрафу ее клетки, путь в нулевые узлы будет равен собственно 0. Штрафы естественно считаются относительно целевой линии.

После того как Дейкстра отработает, нужно дополнительно в каждом "своем" узле, вошедшем в путь, строить путь от входа до выхода. Это не сложно сделать [волновым алгоритмом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B8).

После того как пути построены нужно искать пересечения и выполнять пересчет начиная с перестроения графа Д. Перестроение будет заключаться в увеличении штрафов в "чужих" узлах и разбиении "своих" в соответсвии с пересечениями.

Тут мы подходим к главной проблеме - какие линии пересчитывать!

Забудем Дейкстру. Будем применять вариацию минимакса [алгоритм альфа-бета отсечения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) ([подробнее](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146088/) или [здесь](http://www.dokwork.ru/2012/11/tictactoe.html)). Для альфа-бета отсечения (АБС) требуется строить дерево состояний. Эти состояния будут представлены графами Д для всех линий сразу. Каждое ветвление дерева АБС это выбор очередного узла для одной из линий. На каждом ветвлении АБС граф Д нужно перестраивать и пересчитывать штрафы.

Для АБС очень важны эвристики, вот несколько пришедших мне в голову:

1. В случае трех линий 0, 1 и 2, линия 1 имеет то преимущество что ее штраф за чужие клетки всегда равен 1. Поэтому при выборе линии для пересчета нужно выбирать линию 1 так как вероятность увеличения штрафа ниже.
2. Тоже самое с другого боку, можно подсчитывать количество клеток каждого типа и таким образом получать вероятность увеличения штрафа при пересчете линии.
3. При построении пути, если встречается штрафной узел, можно подсматривать в "чужой" граф Д для :

   1. определения размеров "чужой" области,
   2. быстрого построения пути до более "дешевых" узлов тем же волновиком,
   3. а так же для определения расстояния до концов "чужой" линии предполагая что вероятность пересечения в близких узлах выше.

Comment: Решение не является точным или описано недостаточно понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy За точные решения мне деньги платят. Что не понятно?

Comment: Я сказал "или". Т. е. либо это решение ищет некоторый хороший вариант, но не обязательно оптимальный, либо ты недостаточно его расписал, чтобы стало понятно, почему и как именно находится именно оптимальный вариант.

Comment: @Qwertiy обновил ответ

Comment: Посмотрел. Прошу подтвердить, что решение является поиском достаточно хорошего способа и его оптимальность ен гарантируется.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вначале вообще не учитывать штрафы за пересечения и Дейкстрой пройтись по графу и провести линии. Если на выходе мы не получили пересечений (за исключением точки отправки и точки назначения) то алгоритм закончен. Если пересечения есть, то добавляем в граф дополнительные штрафы за пересечения в узлы, где пролегают текущие линии. Теперь проходимся декстрой снова для каждой линии по очереди, если пути не поменялись, алгоритм закончен, если поменялись снова повторяем этот цикл. В итоге мы придем к той ситуации, когда сократить путь будет уже невозможно и линии останутся неизменными. Нужно не забывать обновлять штрафы за пересечения после каждой дейкстры над каждой линией.